# jquery datatable 1.9.4 sAjaxSource reload data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I use old datatable version (not by choice) and I try to create a datatable with an AJAX source.

Here is my JS Code :

```
var dataTable = $('#my_table').DataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bJQueryUI" : true,
    "fnReloadAjax" : true,
    "sAjaxSource": "http://localhost:8000/ajax_data"
});
```

Here is the table :

```
<table id="failover_record">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

The table is right filled by Datatable after the AJAX query.

My problem is : **When I write text to filter the result the table hasn't reload**.

- **Datatable send a correct AJAX quer**y with **sSearch** field to allow server filter data.
- My **server code return a fine JSON** Data filtered to Datatable.
- But Datatable ignores the server response.

I have no error message.

Do youy have any idea why Datatable ignores the server responses ?

Comment: `"bFilter": false` disables filtering. Also, what is `fnReloadAjax` doing?

Answer (score 1):

I found the error, I disabled **bServerSide** with the following line :

```
"bServerSide": true,
```

and it works.

The line can be removed because default value of **bServerSide** is false.

I hope it will helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Server-side response will be ignored if value of `sEcho` parameter in response doesn't match value of `sEcho` parameter in request.

From the [manual](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side):

> **Reply from the server**
>
> `sEcho` - An unaltered copy of `sEcho` sent from the client side. This parameter will change with each draw (it is basically a draw count) - so it is important that this is implemented.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not my problem. I found it, the **bServerSide** must be disabled.